# Smoke simulation (manta) goes wild when I add wind

Tags: smoke-simulation

I wanted to add some wind to the smoke so it does move a bit sideways. It did work before but now the volume pixels in the domain just go crazy. (see pic) Maybe you can help to fix

[image]

Comment: Please provide blend file

Comment: This sounds like a need to refresh a cache. I’m saying that coming from hair work where a similar thing happens.